# Where to find Microsoft.Exchange.Data.* assemblies

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchange-transport-agents

I am looking at implementing a Microsoft Exchange Transport Agent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579185(v=exchg.140).aspx) to do some email processing, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to get the Microsoft.Exchange.Data.* namespaces/assemblies that I'll need to reference. Do I need to do all of the development on the actual server where Outlook Server is installed? (I tried installing it locally but it won't install on Windows 7.) Is there a place to download these assemblies (downloaded EWS Managed API, but it doesn't have the ones I need)? If not, would I be able to copy the assemblies from the Exchange Server to my local machine so that I can still do my development locally (I'm assuming I'll have to compile and copy to the server to test, but I don't feel like writing my code directly on the server).

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I'm looking to do the same thing and am having trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when trying to install Exchange, you can choose to only install the management studio instead of the whole server. That works on Windows 7 and installs the assemblies I was looking for.

Instructions on how to do so are at http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-install-management-tools/